# Laravel Validation Rule 'same' Always Fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Validation in Controller

```
$this->validate($req, [
  'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min: 6', 'same: conf_password'],
  'conf_password' => ['required', 'string', 'min: 6', 'same: password'],
]);
```

View

```
<input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" 
  placeholder="Enter password" value="{{ old('password') }}">

<input id="conf_password" type="password" class="form-control" 
   name="conf_password" placeholder="Enter password once again"
   value="{{ old('conf_password') }}">
```

It always returns false, also even when I changed it to `confirmed` rule with it `_confirmation` suffix specs.

But I did `dd($req->password == $req->conf_password)`, it returns true. What happened?

Comment: Did you try removing the spaces after `:`?

Comment: @cweiske thanks dude, you saved my life. I searched around for 3 hours only for space.

Comment: Why don't you use `confirmed` https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-confirmed?

Comment: @RossWilson I did, but nothing happened, still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spaces after the `:`.

Comment: Why `same` rule has strict format, when regex, min, and other rule are not. OMG.

Comment: Open a bug for laravel.

Comment: @YosuaLijantoBinar, please remember to accept this answer.